# Shiny: Unwanted space before italicized word

Tags: r, shiny

If you have some experience with the Shiny environment, I would like to ask your help with a little issue. It regards the italicization of text. I have a single italicized word within a normal paragraph, as below:

```
p(".....blabla (", em("italicized)"), "blabla")
```

The problem is a space that pops up just before the italicized word, as in: ".....blabla ( italicized)". Would you know how to cancel it?

The problem arises both locally as well as on my shinyapps.io webpage.

N.B. I already asked in the Shiny Google group but there were no answers.

Thank you so much

Further below, I attach an example of the ui.R for reproducibility, to comply with a request. The error is in the third line from the end.

*As a disclaimer, though, please note that if remotely this example should have any errors with parentheses or such, the unwanted space I get is with all certainty not due to any of those. The code is altogether smooth besides the unwanted space. I humbly believe this example is not very necessary. The error is only about the unwanted space I get from:*

```
p(".....blabla (", em("italicized)"), "blabla")
```

---

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)
library(RCurl)
library(scales)
library(rsconnect)

shinyUI(fluidPage(titlePanel(h3('title', 
    align = 'center', style = 'color:marengo')),

sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,
    h5(strong('blabla'), 
    align = 'center'),
      selectInput('var1', label = 'blabla',
                  choices = list('blabla', 'blabla', 'blabla'),
                  selected = 'blabla'),

      selectInput('var2', label = 'blabla',
                  choices = list('blabla','blabla'),
                  selected = 'blabla'   ),
    helpText('blabla')),

    mainPanel(
    br(),
    plotOutput('plot'),
    p(".....blabla (", em("italicized)"), "blabla"),
    br(),
    height = 8, width = 10))))
```

Comment: Can you create a small working example for reproducibility?

Comment: Try `HTML(paste0(".....blabla (", em("italicized)"), "blabla"))`.

Comment: Hi Pierre. That was spot on. Thank you so very much.

I actually put the `HTML(paste0(` within `p()` in order to keep formatting tags I also had for it. 

So, + many ups for you.

Comment: @PierreLafortune: would you add an answer for that, so Pablo can accept it? Pablo, we don't use [solved] title addendums here - we have an answer acceptance system for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `p()` might have unwanted side effects. Instead try:

```
HTML(paste0(".....blabla (", em("italicized)"), "blabla"))
```

Comment: I did try with HTML only, but the `align='justify'` tag (which wasn't present in the example though) wouldn't work. Yet, with `p(HTML(paste0(`, it all worked perfectly.